# Active Model Serializer not responding with the correct attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I am working on a `rails-api` project where I am using `active model serialiazer`. But unfortunately its not working as expected.  This is my `V1::HuntsController`

```
class V1::HuntsController < V1::MainController
  def index
    render json: Hunt.all
  end
end
```

My hunts serializer looks like this

```
class HuntSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  belongs_to :user
  attributes :id,:title,:picture_url,:clue
  private
  def picture_url
    object.picture.url
  end
end
```

But in my `response` i am getting all the attributes from `hunt`. I tried to explicitly define serializer to avoid versioning issues as well.

```
render json: {data: Hunt.all } ,each_serializer: HuntSerializer
```

But nothing seems to work. In the logs I can see,

```
[active_model_serializers] Rendered V1::HuntSerializer with Hash (32.36ms)
```

Whats happening here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try
`render json: Hunt.all, each_serializer: HuntSerializer` (no need for data root)

then to verify that the serializer gets hit, put a `byebug` in the body of the picture_url function. if the `byebug` gets hit, you are indeed using your serializer. (must have gem byebug included in gemfile)

Comment: As I had clearly mentioned in the question, I tried the suggestion you have mentioned with no luck. I tried ``debugger`` also and its not being called. SO not sure whats going on here.

Comment: sorry I understood what you meant. I tried that and its working. Why `` {data: Hunt.all }``   not working? Doesnt it call ``as_json`` method?

Comment: It's not working because you're 1.) preventing AMS from inspecting the object and retrieving the corresponding serializer (HuntSerializer) and 2.) even with each_serializer it doesn't work because `{ data: Hunt.all }` is not an array.

Comment: also, `debugger` wont work on server side, because thats a javascript  concept. `byebug` or `pry` is what usually is used for debugging on server side. lastly, if this solved the issue for you, please accept my answer :)

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Btw debugger exists in rails also, actually ruby gem included in rails. So you can use debugger in rails.